# How to dynamically register different click event to specific children of div?

Tags: jquery

What is the best approach to register custom click event to parent div's children, different on click event to every different child?

This is my markup:

```
<div class="summary">
    <div class="icon add"></div>
    <div class="count"</div>
    <div class="arrow"</div>
</div>
```

I need to register the '`icon add`' class  different event handler.

### First approach:

I've tried (**does not work** - only the `*:not(.icon.add)`):

```
var $summery = $('.summary');
$summery.on("click", "*:not(.icon.add)", e => {
    //do something1;
});
$summery.on("click", ".icon.add", e => {
    //do something2;
});
```

### Second approach:

eventually what i did is this (**it works**):

```
$summary.find(".count").on("click", null, e => {
    //do something1
});
$summary.find(".arrow").on("click", null, e => {
    //do something1
});
$summary.find(".icon.add").on("click", null, e => {
    //do something2
});
```

**Is there any way to solve this problem using the first approach?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's really possible to use `not` like that. If they're all different, your 2nd way seems completely fine to me.

If the actions are similar you can use commas to separate:

```
$summary.find(".count, .arrow, .icon.add").on("click", null, e => {
    //do something2
});
```